# Converting composed objects to json in Go

Tags: json, types, go, subclass

I am new to Go and am unsure about how to approach this problem. In OOP terms, I have a base class of Animal and two subclasses of Cat and Dog. I want to specify a ToJson method for Animal which will work for all animals.

My problem is that when I call dog.ToJson() I only get the Dog properties of dog and none of the Animal properties.

How can I make ToJson work as expected (ie [with recursion](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal))?

edit: Changed code to reflect suggestions in answer by lbonn, which I could not get to work how I want it to.
edit2: consistency in question following code change

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Animal struct {
    Name string
}

type Cat struct {
    CatProperty int64
    Animal
}

type Dog struct {
    DogProperty int64
    Animal
}

func ToJson(i interface{}) []byte {
        data,err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic("???")
    }
    return data
}

func main() {
    dog := Dog{}
    dog.Name = "rex"
    dog.DogProperty = 2
    fmt.Println(string(ToJson(dog)))
    // Prints {"DogProperty":2}
    // I want it to print {"Name":"rex","DogProperty":2}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Json encoding of anonymous fields was dropped from go 1. Hopefully it will be back in go 1.1. See  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/jYMHbEv44r4 for more details.

So the best you can get with the standard library right now (with go 1) is http://play.golang.org/p/LncNFeN8ys

You can always use skelterjohn's patch https://github.com/skelterjohn/json/ to support anonymous fields till go 1.1 is released.

Or use tip, installing from source that has this issue fixed. see https://codereview.appspot.com/6460044

Comment: I updated to the latest version using `hg clone -r 492fdf07797e https://code.google.com/p/go` and all is good, my json is being created as I expected. Thanks for the great info.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the `ToJson` method applies to the anonymous field `Animal` of `Dog`. The call `d.ToJson` is only a visibility shortcut to `d.Animal.ToJson`.
[GoLang Tutorials: Anonymous fields in struct](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.jp/2011/06/anonymous-fields-in-structs-like-object.html)

Here, I would write a function instead of a method (a simple wrapper around `Marshal`):

```
func ToJson(i interface{}) []byte {
    data,err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic("???")
    }
    return data
}
```

This is not specific to animals or dogs but it doesn't really need to.

More generally, there is no real notion of inheritance in go. The object paradigm used in the language is quite different from mainstream OOP, like in Java or C++. The [Go FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#types) provides some good clarifications about it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not understanding... from http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal I see "Marshal traverses the value v recursively". I assume in my example it should create a json representation of dog including DogProperty and (from the recursion) also include the Name property from Animal. But when I call Marshal the result doesn't include Name. Can you please help me understand this, preferably by posting an example which gives the json {"DogProperty":2,"Name":"rex"}? Also, thanks for the useful link, it helped clarify my understanding of how composition works in Go.

Comment: If you want to print all the values from dog, you need to call `Marshal` on the whole dog object. In your example, `Marshal` is called on the anonymous field `Animal` inside of `Dog`. Thus, it can't see the fields of `Dog` which are not contained in it. You can try the code I posted in my answer and use `fmt.Println(string(ToJson(d))` and it will print the whole `Dog`.

Comment: Please see my edit to the code in the question, which now includes your function. It does not seem to include the Name property, I only get `{"DogProperty":2}` in my output

Comment: Well, it does on my machine, that's odd. Which version of go are you using ?

Comment: I am using go1.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. Please see http://play.golang.org/p/wntp7n7K8Y which also does not give the desired result.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm using a devel version, that's why it works here. rputikar's answer explains the issue.